# Support and stalks at generic points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be an noetherian scheme, $Y$ an irreducible closed subscheme of $X$ with generic point $y$ and $\mathscr G$ a coherent sheaf of $\mathscr O_X$-modules. Consider the following statement:

*If $\mathscr G_y\ne 0,$ then $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathscr G)=Y.$*

I know this holds for $X=Y$ but I think it isn't correct otherwise because I can take $Y=y$ to be a closed point and $\mathscr G = \mathscr O_X$ and violate the statement.

But unless I am reading it wrong, the proof of the "lemme de dévissage", Theorem 3.1.2 in EGA III, and even more explicitly the statement of Corollary 3.1.3 which follows it, both claim just the above statement. I am confused; could someone please explain how I should understand what's written in EGA (or is it perhaps a mistake and if so, how should one correct it)? Thanks a lot!

**Edit:** Let me elaborate on what bugs me. Theorem 3.1.2 only contains the condition that for every irreducible closed subset $Y\subset X$ with a generic point $y$ there should exist a sheaf $\mathscr G\in \mathbf K'$ such that $\mathscr G_y$ is a one-dimensional vector space over $k(y).$ But then in the proof when $\mathscr G$ is called upon (second paragraph on p. 116) there is a passage:

> Par hypothèse, il y a un $\mathscr O_X$-Module cohérent $\mathscr  G$ (nécessairement de support $Y$) tel que $\mathscr G_y$ soint un $k(y)$-espace vectoriel de dimension $1.$

Then in the course of the proof this is used in the proof and the fact that $\mathscr G^m$ has support inside $Y$ is reiterated.
Then finally the statement of Corollary 3.1.3 literally contains the following:

> ... est remplacée par $\mathscr G_y\ne 0$ (ce qui équivaut à $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathscr G) = Y$).

From all of that it's hard not to come to the conclusion that the statement I wrote above is being implied.

Comment: I couldn't find the claim in the cited place of EGA. Are you sure about the reference? Could you perhaps quote the relevant section you are referring to?

Comment: I believe it should be EGA III.

Comment: Of course it's EGA III and not EGA II - sorry for the typo! It's corrected now. For what its worth, what I'm referring to is on pages 115 & 116.

Comment: The statement “if $\mathscr G_y\neq 0$, then $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathscr G)\supseteq Y$” makes more sense, right?

Comment: See that would make perfect sense, but I'm not convinced that's what's going on here. The proof of the dévissage theorem 3.1.2 uses in an important  way that $\mathscr G$ is $0$ on the complement of $Y.$ That shows that a specified pair of morphisms $v\colon \mathscr H_0\to\mathscr G^m$ and $w\colon\mathscr H_0\to\mathscr F$ have kernel and cokernel equal to $0$ on $X - Y$ which is needed to invoke noetherian recursion.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify how you want to use said theorem here. The last sentence of Theorem (3.1.2) reads “Then every coherent $\mathscr O_X$-module with support in $X'$ lies in $K'$”. So it doesn't say anything if $\mathscr G = \mathscr O_X$.

Comment: I didn't want to take $\mathscr G=\mathscr O_X$ to give a counterexample to theorem 3.1.2, merely to the statement I made in the OP above, i.e. an example of a sheaf for which $\mathscr G_y \ne 0$ but $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathscr G)$ isn't equal to $Y.$I editied the question to make it more transparent what part of the proof of Theorem 3.1.2 and statement of Corollary 3.1.3 I'm having qualms with. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme; one can prove that $X$ has finitely many irreducible components and they are in bijection with the generic points of $X$.

Let $Y$ be an irreducible components of $X$, and let $\eta$ be the generic point of $Y$, I recall that:
\begin{equation}
Y=\overline{\{\eta\}}^X.
\end{equation}
Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, or more in general $\mathcal{G}$ is locally of finite type; by definition:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Supp}\mathcal{G}=\{x\in X\mid\mathcal{G}_x\neq0\},
\end{equation}
considering the zero morphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules
\begin{equation}
0\to\mathcal{G}
\end{equation}
passing to stalks: $0_x\to\mathcal{G}_x$ is an epimorphism of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-modules if and only if $\mathcal{G}_x=0_x$.

Let $x\notin\mathrm{Supp}\mathcal{G}$, by hypothesis there exists an open affine neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\mathcal{G}_{|U}$ is associated to a finite $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-module $M$, let $\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$ a generator system of $M$; by hypothesis:
\begin{equation}
\forall k\in\{1,\dots,n\},\,\exists V_k\subseteq U\,\text{open}\mid s_{k|V_k}=0\Rightarrow x\in V=\bigcap_{k=1}^nV_k\,\text{is open and}\,\mathcal{G}_{|V}=\widetilde{0}.
\end{equation}
From all this, for any $x\notin\mathrm{Supp}\mathcal{G}$ there exists an open neighbourhood $V_x$ such that $\mathcal{G}_{|V_x}=\widetilde{0}$; then
\begin{equation}
V=\bigcup_{x\notin\mathrm{Supp}\mathcal{G}}V_x\,\text{is open and}\,\mathcal{G}_{|V}=0
\end{equation}
and therefore
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Supp}\mathcal{G}=X\setminus V\,\text{is a closed subset of}\,X;
\end{equation}
by hypothesis:
\begin{equation}
\eta\in\mathrm{Supp}\mathcal{G}\cap Y=\mathrm{Supp}_Y\mathcal{G}\Rightarrow Y=\mathrm{Supp}_Y\mathcal{G}.
\end{equation}
**Remark**: I had use only the hypothesis that $Y$ is a scheme and $\mathcal{G}$ is locally of finite type.

**Update**: Grothendieck and Dieudonné affirm that we can reduce the proof to the case that $\mathcal{IF}=0$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is the ideal sheaf associated to $Y$ then:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}\cong i_{*}\left(i^{*}\mathcal{F}\right);
\end{equation}
my idea is: by hypothesis, we can assume that there exists a coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module $\mathcal{G}^{\prime}$ such that $\mathcal{G}^{\prime}_{\eta}$ is a $\kappa(\eta)$-vector space of dimension $1$; then we can get
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{G}=i_{*}\mathcal{G}^{\prime}.
\end{equation}
Because $Y$ is a closed (reduced) subscheme of $X$, then the inclusion $i:Y\to X$ is (quasi-)separated ([B], corollary 7.4.10) and quasi-compact ([B], lemma 7.3.8 and proposition 7.3.9) and therefore $\mathcal{G}$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module ([B], proposition 6.9.9), and in particular:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Supp}\mathcal{G}=Y\,\text{([B], exercise 6.9.5)}.
\end{equation}
[B] Bosch S., *Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra*

Comment: This is all good and well, but really all you've proved is that $\mathscr F_\eta \ne 0$ implies $\operatorname{Supp}_Y(\mathscr F) = Y.$ But the EGA passages cited in the original post suggest that it should further imply that $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathscr F) = Y,$ i.e. that $\textit{global}$ support is also precisely $Y.$ I don't think you've shown that.

Comment: No, you have wrong! The hypothesis of _lemma de dévissage_ is that $\mathcal{F}_{\eta}$ is not zero for any generic point $\eta$ of the irreducible components $Y$ of $X$. How do you conclude, using the hypothesis of Noetherianess of $X$?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please elaborate a bit on what it is I am wrong about? Are you saying that your proof actually shows that $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathscr F) = Y$? Or are you saying that I'm misunderstanding EGA and it is not claimed in the $\textit{proof}$ of lemma de dévissage that $\mathscr G$ (as it's denoted there) can be chosen so that its support is precisely $Y$?

Comment: I apologize for my absence. __I had misunderstand__ the hypothesis of _lemma de dévissage_; first, I had prove that the support of a sheaf of locally finite type is a closed subset of the scheme, because I believed that you was confused on this particular; second I propose you a possible solution. Sorry me again.

Comment: I see, that thing is that I should take $\mathscr G$ to satisfy the conditions of the lemma $\textbf{on $Y$ and not on $X$}$. Now everything makes sense! Thank you very much Armando!